# Pandas : Adding new rows to existing dataframe keeping the same distribution across all columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with pandas dataframe. I want to increase the size of my dataframe say from 1000 to 4432 (not exactly n times, n being a natural number) . I want to make sure that the distribution of value in each column remains the same after increasing the size. 
For Example, if I have column name `Car` with given distribution existing 100 rows.

```
Maruti  30%
Ford    10%
Tata    40%
Others  10%
```

I would like to keep this share same after increasing the size to 4432

The column could range, numeric, categorical.
 On more example would be `Age` with a distribution like

```
20-30   20%
30-40   40%
40-50   25%
50-60   15%
```

Again I would like to keep this distribution same while increasing the size of Dataframe.

Comment: Could you please add an example of "current distribution","adding new data", "new distribution"

Comment: Hi,
I'm not sure what your problem is. How do you plan to increase the size of your DataFrame ? Are you generating your data ?
The trivial answer would be that you just have to increase the size of your DataFrame with observations that will respect your previous distribution...

Moreover, what did you try ? Can you provide your code ?

Comment: @VikasNS the two example are of current distribution. There is nothing called new distribution as i would like to keep the distribution same. adding new data is adding new row withe same values. kind of duplicating rows with same distribution.

Comment: @AdrienPacifico Yes " just have to increase the size of your DataFrame with observations that will respect your previous distribution" for all the columns.

Comment: @MdDanish, I feel that your question is not clear, you should spend time to think about what you really want to achieve (usually the hardest part), then edit your question. 

Provide more info about your data, give code, state what you try, etc.


Please read : 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask


Good luck !

Comment: @AdrienPacifico I am very much clear what I want. Yeah, not the best of presentation. If you could see the comment in the answer below you may get what I want. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following function rounds target number of rows *per unique value*, so the distribution is closer to the desired one than if you just duplicate the whole dataframe. In the following example, for multiplier 1.5 you can actually preserve the distribution, even though the simple `concat` won't give you `1.5x` of the original dataframe.

```
def increase_df(df, column, multiplier):
    new_value_counts = (df[column].value_counts() * multiplier).apply(lambda value: int(round(value)))
    values = sum(([value] * count for value, count in new_value_counts.to_dict().items()), [])
    return pd.DataFrame(values)

df = pd.DataFrame(["Mumbai"] * 4 + ["Kolkata"] * 2 + ["Chennai"] * 2 + ["Delhi"] * 4, columns=['city']) 
print df
       city
0   Mumbai 
1   Mumbai 
2   Mumbai 
3   Mumbai 
4   Kolkata
5   Kolkata
6   Chennai
7   Chennai
8   Delhi  
9   Delhi  
10  Delhi  
11  Delhi 

# here the distribution can be preserved exactly
print increase_df(df, 'city', 1.5)
          0
0   Kolkata
1   Kolkata
2   Kolkata
3   Chennai
4   Chennai
5   Chennai
6   Delhi  
7   Delhi  
8   Delhi  
9   Delhi  
10  Delhi  
11  Delhi  
12  Mumbai 
13  Mumbai 
14  Mumbai 
15  Mumbai 
16  Mumbai 
17  Mumbai 

# here it can't, because the target number of rows per value is fractional. 
# The function rounds that number to the nearest int, so the distribution is as close to the original one as it can get.
print increase_df(df, 'city', 1.8)

          0
0   Kolkata
1   Kolkata
2   Kolkata
3   Kolkata
4   Chennai
5   Chennai
6   Chennai
7   Chennai
8   Delhi  
9   Delhi  
10  Delhi  
11  Delhi  
12  Delhi  
13  Delhi  
14  Delhi  
15  Mumbai 
16  Mumbai 
17  Mumbai 
18  Mumbai 
19  Mumbai 
20  Mumbai 
21  Mumbai
```

Comment: Yeah That's  why i asked N is not a natural no. so I wasn't sure whether or not i can preserve the distribution.

Comment: Got you. I updated the answer. Depending on the multiplier and number of rows per value in the original dataframe, sometimes you can preserve the original distribution (even for non-natural multipliers), and sometimes you can't (when target number of rows gets fractional for some values).

Answer (score 0):

A trivial way would be to duplicate all the rows a certain number of times to reach the required number of observations.

Let's say you have a dataframe `df` and you want `num_reqd` observations. All rows duplicated `(num_reqd//df.shape[0])` times should give you a little under `num_reqd` observations.

```
import pandas as pd
new_df = pd.concat([df] * (num_reqd//df.shape[0]), axis=1)
```

But if you wanted to mix the data up a bit further, you can use `numpy` to shuffle the values in your columns.

```
import numpy as np
new_df.apply(np.random.shuffle, axis=0)
```

You can concat the values from `df` if you want to keep the original observations too.

```
new_df = pd.concat([df, new_df], axis=1)
```

Comment: The no. of times i have to duplicate is no a natural number. Hence the issue that whether or not i can preserve the Distribution.